# how to execute piece of code in hadoop cluster nodes?

Tags: hadoop2

```
        I created a hadoop multinode cluster and my target is to know processor information of all nodes in the cluster by running jar file in master.I have the code to know processor info in a node.How can i run this code in all nodes and retrieve the processor information using java.
        thanks in advance for help..

        Driver code:

    Here i have used only mapper class    

       public class ProcInfoCluster extends Configured implements Tool {

            @Override
            public int run(String[] arg0) throws Exception {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if(arg0.length<2)
                {
                    System.out.println("please provide the output file paths");
                    return -1;
                }

                JobConf conf=new JobConf(ProcInfoCluster.class);
                conf.setJobName("ProcesorInfo");
                FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(conf, new Path(arg0[0]));
                FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(conf,new Path(arg0[1]));
                conf.setMapperClass(ProcInfoMapper.class);
                //conf.setReducerClass(WordReducer.class);
                conf.setMapOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
                conf.setMapOutputValueClass(Text.class);
                conf.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
                conf.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);
                JobClient.runJob(conf);     
                return 0;
            }
            public static void main(String args[])
            throws Exception
            {
            int exitCode=ToolRunner.run(new ProcInfoCluster(), args);   
            System.exit(exitCode);
            }


        }



        Mapper code:


    Here in this mapper code i have written code to know processor information and tried to send it as key value pairs

        public class ProcInfoMapper extends MapReduceBase implements Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text,Text>
        {

            @Override
```

//map function to retrieve processor information of all nodes
                public void map(LongWritable key, Text value,
                        OutputCollector output, Reporter reporter)
                        throws IOException {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

```
                String no=System.getenv("PROCESSOR_ARCHITEW6432");
    //to know processor info
                System.out.println(no);
                String s=new String("ProcInfo");
                output.collect(new Text(s), new Text(no));
            }

        }

and i had a doubt that whether we can write a map reduce application only with mapper class without the reducer class
```

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand your question. You want to run a MapReduce application over Hadoop Cluster?

Comment: yes sir,similar kind of thing..actually i want to know how to run a piece of code in all nodes of hadoop cluster and get information from all nodes and send to output directory..i.e, to know processor information all individual nodes and send to output directory..i tried with map reduce application like

Comment: i tried to do with map reduce application by not using reducer,only using mapper. In mapper i have written code to know processor information and tried to execute it but it is not working..

Comment: First of all, you should be install Hadoop (single mode or cluster mode). Next, you should be test the hadoop examples work fine (Pi example, wordcount example). At the end, you should be search a wordcount example online, and coding and try to compile/execute. There are tons of tutorials for that. What are your doubt?